# jquery cycle pager doesn't init

Tags: jquery, cycle

I have used jquery cycle plugin for slider on my page,
but in my code, pager doesn't want to run even init..

With this code:

```
$('#slider').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    timeout: 8000,
    speed: 1000,
    prev: '#slider_prev',
    next: '#slider_next',
    pager: '#nav',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
        alert("AAA");
        return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + 
                     '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>';
    }
});​
```

It should fire alert when building pager, but it doesn't even run pager builder function..

Here's an [example page](http://dream.dreamware.cz/).

Can anybody tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: #nav should contain all pager links, but it doesnt.. and alert didn't fire too

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the full version of the cycle plugin

http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js

Apparently the version "pager" version does not support it "jquery.cycle.lite.js"